How to prove a subspace of a normed space is closed?
Let $(X,||.||)$ be Banach space. Let $Y=S(\vec0,1)$ be a subspace of $(X,||.||)$.
I want to show that $Y$ is closed in $(X,||.||)$, so that I can say $Y$ is complete, because we have a theorem "A subspace of a normed space is complete if and only if it is closed".
I need to show that $Y=\overset{-}{Y}$, in order $Y$ to be closed. First, it is clear that $Y \subseteq \overset{-}{Y}$. So, we are left to show if $x \in \overset{-}{Y}, \; \text{then} \; \;  x \in Y$.
Let $x \in \overset{-}{Y} $, then there exists $r>0$ such that the open ball $B(x,r)$ other than $x$ intersects with $Y$. Thus, there must be another $y \in \left( B(x,r) \cap Y \right) $, then $||x-y||<r$ and $||y||=1.$
Now, $\left| \; ||x||-||y|| \; \right| \leq ||x-y|| <r $, this implies that $| \; ||x|| -1 \; |<r$, thus we obtain
$$1-r<||x||<1+r.$$
From this point, I can not go further to ensure that $||x||=1$.
So, I kindly ask for your help so that I can make the proof complete.

Every ball $B(x,r)$ intersects with $Y.$ So $1-r<|x|<1+r$ for every $r>0.$

What is $Y=S(\vec0,1)$?

I just Assumed that $Y=S(\vec0,1)$, so that I can write the proof easier.
